# Oracle Fusion Middleware 11g web tier utilities installation

Tags: oracle

While installing Oracle fusion Middleware 11g web tier utilities at step 7 following error occurs and stops installation process.

> Installation Failed. Prepare Session failed SEVERE:Values for the following variables could not be obtained from the command line or response file(s): MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME(MyOracleSupportUsername) Silent install cannot continue.

I could not figure out what is wrong , please help ...

Answer (score 1):

The message suggests you're doing a silent install, so have you created/modified a response file as described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/install.1112/e35859/silent_install.htm)? The `MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME` is mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24269_01/doc.11120/e23960/silent_install.htm), but its interaction with the other parameters isn't always obvious. There is more detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/em.112/e12255/oui3_response_files.htm#sthref268).

Assuming you don't want to get security updates, you need to set `DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES` to `TRUE` (although I seem to recall having to supply the MSO credentials anyway, but not sure which version I saw that and it seemed like a bug). If you do want security updates then leave that as `FALSE` and set the MSO credentials  to appropriate values.

Comment: Kindly, have a look to the thread [Failed while installing Oracle fusion Middleware 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428677/failed-while-installing-oracle-fusion-middleware-11g-release-1-11-1-1-7)